# Distinguish where topics belongs to

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags, superuser, scope

Hey Meta!

I'm not sure sometimes if I should flag or not topic like this one [how do i get vim's foldtext to show the number of lines on the right side of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316334/how-do-i-get-vims-foldtext-to-show-the-number-of-lines-on-the-right-side-of-the) as "belongs to superuser".

Here is my reasoning :

1. This is clearly a software used by programmers to code (but not only)
2. This is clearly an advanced usage of the software (power use)
3. The SU community would really be interested to do some things like this for other purposes.

More generally, how do we distinguish where does topic belongs when they can overlap focus of many SE sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, vim falls in the "software tools commonly used by programmers" clause of the SO [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), so it's okay to ask about it on SO.  If someone *wants* to ask a vim question on SU they can, but we shouldn't migrate them there.

In general, the site-specific FAQ pages have the guidelines.  If you see a question that *doesn't* fit in the guidelines of a site it's posted on, then you can vote to close or flag it.  If it's a borderline case you can always ask here on Meta (or the site-specific Meta).